# Ghostscript.NET pdf to image not working on windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, azure, ghostscript.net

I am trying to convert pdf first page to image using [**Ghostscript.NET**](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com) it works fine on local IIS but fails on the Azure web app with the following error:

> [GhostscriptException: Delegate of an exported function couldn't be
>   created for symbol 'gsapi_revision']
>   Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLibrary.Initialize() +865
>   Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLibrary..ctor(GhostscriptVersionInfo
>   version, Boolean fromMemory) +178
>   Ghostscript.NET.Interpreter.GhostscriptInterpreter..ctor(GhostscriptVersionInfo
>   version, Boolean fromMemory) +48
>   Ghostscript.NET.Viewer.GhostscriptViewer.Open(String path,
>   GhostscriptVersionInfo versionInfo, Boolean dllFromMemory) +75
>   Ghostscript.NET.Viewer.GhostscriptViewer.Open(Stream stream,
>   GhostscriptVersionInfo versionInfo, Boolean dllFromMemory) +59
>   Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer.Open(Stream stream,
>   GhostscriptVersionInfo versionInfo, Boolean dllFromMemory) +40
>   VirtualWindow.Dropzone.Pages.Home.btnUpload_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +270
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +116
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +108
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +12
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +31    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3582

My code is below

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        string ghostDllPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/External");
        GhostscriptRasterizer rasterizer = null;
        GhostscriptVersionInfo vesion = null;
        if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
            vesion = new Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo(new Version(0, 0, 0), ghostDllPath + @"\gsdll64.dll", string.Empty, Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLicense.GPL);
        else
            vesion = new Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo(new Version(0, 0, 0), ghostDllPath + @"\gsdll32.dll", string.Empty, Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLicense.GPL);
        using (rasterizer = new Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer())
        {
            rasterizer.Open(fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream, vesion, false);
            if (rasterizer.PageCount > 0)
            {
                  int dpi = 90;
                  System.Drawing.Image img = rasterizer.GetPage(dpi, dpi, 1);
                  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                  {
                       string file = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
                       img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                       Response.ContentType = "image/png";
                       byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
                       Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                       Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file);
                       Response.Flush();
                   }
            }
            rasterizer.Close();
        }   
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your gsdll64.dll being included in the package? Right click-> properties on the dll, should be BuildAction = None, Copy to output directory = Copy Always.

Comment: Yes it is. Infact my local environment is also 64bit. But both 32bit and 64bit versions are present.

Comment: And the path as well: If you are publishing from within Visual Studio, check the build output after publish. Search the build output for gsdll64.dll, there will be a section on the files copied and should show ...PackageTmp\bin\External\gsdll64.dll

Answer (score 3):

Ok found the issue. Everything including the paths were correctly setup. My site was hosted on free plan and hence it was configured to be on 32-bit environment.
My local environment was 64 bit which was working. So I redownloaded the `gsdll32.dll`. Updated azure and it started working on azure too.

Problem was with wrong `gsdll32.dll`.

Comment: where did you get the gsdll32.dll and gsdll64.dll from?

Comment: You are using native Ghostscript library (gsdll32.dll) compiled for 32bit systems in a 64bit process. You need to use gsdll64.dll. 64bit native Ghostscript library can be downloaded from http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html